# Applications of simultaneous diagonalization of quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms, applications, diagonalization

If $A$ and $B$ are square symmetric matrices and, additionally, one of them, say $B$, is positively defined, then there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that

$$S^{\top}\!AS=D \quad\text{and}\quad S^{\top}\!BS=I,$$

where $D$ is diagonal and $I$ is the identity matrix.

**Question:** *Why it is important to be able to do such reduction simultaneously (by a single matrix $S$)? Where this can be applied?*

**P.S.:** I heard about some applications for differential equations, but only in general phrases.

Comment: What else do you know about S? Is it orthogonal by chance?

Comment: @NateIverson: Not necessarily.

Comment: is $S$ unitary here?

Comment: I don't think it's diagonalization unless $S^T=S^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also known as the modal decomposition in engineering applications, specially in vibrations. It is very useful for the decoupling of differential equations.

A good example of its use in this context is given in pp.160-173 of *Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua*, which preview is fortunately available 
in [google books](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=-eq7AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT160). In special, pp.163-173 illustrates the use of this technique for a scenario with two coupled pendulums.